# ImportError: No module named allauth. Django

Tags: python, django, pycharm

in a project with django, when I do "python manage.py runserver" I get this error traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 250, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 94, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named allauth
```

I installed allauth using pip3 install allauth.
And this is my INSTALLED_APPS :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'music.apps.MusicConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
]
```

Comment: The traceback shows `C:\Python27` -- you are not running Python 3 when you get that error. If you using a virtualenv, then switch into it before running `runserver`. If not, try `python3 manage.py runserver`.

Comment: what should I do ? because in the project interpreter I have python3.6.2 !!

Comment: Did you try using `python3` instead of `python`, as I suggested?

Comment: yes and it shows that python3 is not recognized :

'python3' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.

Comment: I can't help any further I'm afraid -- I don't use Windows very often.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install `django-allauth` package.
In other words, please run following command.

- in case of using pip

```
$ pip install django-allauth
```

- in case of using pipenv

```
$ pipenv install django-allauth
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have activated the virtualenv in which you have installed allauth

Comment: source env/bin/activate

Comment: Thank you, but I did solve the problem, I just had to delete the python 2.7 version.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the exact same python interpreter to run your Django project that the one you are using to install packages to with `pip`?

I would recommend using `virtualenv`to install packages to it, and then using it in your Django project.

One thing that might be happening is that you have multiple interpreters installed on your machine. I.E. Python 2, and Python 3. In that case, **do make sure** you are pip installing to the same interpreter you are using to run your Django project.

I.E.:

```
$ pip install allauth
```

What happens if you do:

```
$ python
> import allauth
```

Comment: For my version of python[Python 3.6.6], this is what worked: `pip install django-allauth`